# How to add code (or markup) dynamically to the view code from controller MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my controller, the view is returned as usual

```
return new View(myModel);
```

What I would like is to add some extra code to the view. E.g. under a certain condition, to "wrap" the whole view markup inside a @section. For example, my view is

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
```

And after processing the controller's action, I want the view returned to be

```
@section MySection{
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Its generally a bad idea that your controller injecting markup for a view.

Why don't you enhance your view model to contain the original view model and this condition?

```
class MyViewModel {
   MyModelType MyModel { get; set; }
   bool Wrap { get; set; }
}
```

in the view...

```
@if (!Model.Wrap) {
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
}
@section MySection {
   @if (Model.Wrap) {
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is I wanted a "shortcut", to not have to alter the view. the reason is I have a lot of views (about 40 entities, each with own index / create / delete / edit / details) which makes 200(!!!) views to change. That's why I wanted some "markup injection". Controller code is generated with a  codegen, and I could change it to add code injection part to handle it all for all entities. Any other idea?